# swift declare and array contains dictionary

Tags: swift

```
team: [
    [
        {
            type: "profile",
            assists: 8,
        },
        {
            type: "profile",
            assists: 9,
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            type: "profile",
            assists: 8,
        },
        {
            type: "profile",
            assists: 9,
        },
    ]
]
```

This is my data,how can I  declare a variable?

```
var info = Array<Dictionary<String, String>()>
var info = Array<Dictionary<String, Int>()>
```

are both not OK

and I want to edit the variable add a dictionary.
How can I declare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following syntax:

```
var info = [[[String: AnyObject]]]()
```

Better yet, you can use a `struct`:

```
struct TeamMember {
    var type: String
    var assists: Int
}

var test: [[TeamMember]] = [
    [
        TeamMember(type: "x", assists: 0),
        TeamMember(type: "x", assists: 0)
    ],
    [
        TeamMember(type: "x", assists: 0),
        TeamMember(type: "x", assists: 0)
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you.
Actually,My data is like

{
    type: "profile",
 assists: 8,
 name:"text"
},
has many property

maybe 
 var info = [[[String: AnyObject]]]()

is better

Answer (score 0):

I guess your type is the following : [[[String: AnyObject]]], an array of array of dictionary with string keys and undefined objects.